# Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration(IEESC) related popup is coming after uploading project in IIS

Tags: json, iis

```
          I uploaded my project in IIS which was working fine in local but in windows server 2008 R2 it was showing the above attached issue after login(Please check the attached image). The above issue was coming because Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration(IEESC) was on, so I make it off but still my page was not working.
```

Page Behavior:  1) No page error .Also no 404 and 403 error.(Even if CustomError mode is On)
2) Controls including grid view was not getting filled up from database by JSON call.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  1)  Enable .json file extension simply follow this instructions. Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types
          Click "New". Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.
               2) Add the following line in web.config file
                       
                                    
                                    
                                    
                        
3) If you deploy your application to IIS your URI must include your application name as well. So, as your application name is QCValueStream, then your URI must be http://localhost/QCValueStream/ManageProjects/GetManageProjectsData/5.
   You can automatically detect your base Uri and have it prepend by adding a line in your master page(Asp.net web application) or shared _Layout.cshtml(Asp.net MVC):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var config = {
             contextPath: '@Url.Content("~")'
          }
           var baseUri = config.contextPath;
           //or
           var baseUri = '@Url.Content("~")';


          //Then in your JS you prepend by:

   //Incorrect  JSON Call
```

$.getJSON('/ManageProjects/GetManageProjectsData?', { searchText: inputsearchText }, function (data) {
                    myData = data;
               });

```
   //Correct  JSON Call

        $.getJSON(baseUri +'/ManageProjects/GetManageProjectsData?', { searchText: inputsearchText }, function (data) {
                myData = data;
           });

  </script>
```

Note: Check the below url to make off Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration for Administrator or user.
http://www.aurelp.com/2013/01/16/how-to-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-step-by-step/